# Ubuntu 14 virtual machine won't boot

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I was given a virtual machine of Ubuntu 14 that would not boot and would display:

```
kernel panic not syncing vfs unable to mount root fs on unknown-block 0 0
```

After looking around, I figured I could try fixing it by booting into recovery mode and using boot-repair.

It did something which gave me a new error. It looks like it's booting but then it gets stuck at either:

```
Restoring solver state
```

or

```
stopping system v runlevel compatibility
```

I would like help on suggestions on how I can get it boot again. Note: I was told it's Ubuntu 14 and I have the root password. But it boots into Lubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given a VM? How? Unless there's data you need, I'd just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @AndroidDev I should elaborate. I was given a zip file with a lot of files. But if I go to the vmware workstation and select open a virtual machine and I can use the .vmx file that was in the the zip file. That's the broken Ubuntu. I've thought about reinstalling it, but I would like to keep the files.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in case someone one day comes across the same situation.

I simply booted into safe mode and selected:

> dpkg

It was resolved and I was able to boot back in normally. 
However, reverting back to the last kernel can also fix the problem since the current kernel was corrupted.